# How to hold the money for some time and release the money in paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment-processing

I have a requirement the user will register for watching videos. After the user has register then we need to hold the money for a period (varies depends on the video's ). Then after completing the period then we need to release the money to the end user. We are acting as a mediator for the user and the end user. How can i able to do that using paypal.

Is this functionality is available in paypal.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments) (Chained Payments), and utilize the delayed payments feature.

Comment: Can we implement this in the mini layout page which uses iframe template.

Comment: Yes, you can use chained payments in the embedded flow.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by Express Checkout APIs (using the DoAuthorization and DoCapture API calls). More details are here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf